# How to implement Benjamini-Hochberg in R?

Tags: r

Here's the codes I've attempted so far: v=vector of p values, alpha=target FDR

```
bh=function(v,alpha=.1){
    sorted.v<-sort(v)    
    dif<-sorted.v-alpha
    neg.dif<-dif[dif<0]
    pos.dif<-neg.dif[length(neg.dif)]
    index<-dif==pos.dif
    p.cutoff<-sorted.v[index]
    ## (Comment:below will return the cutoff value)
    p.cutoff
    p.sig<-v[v<=p.cutoff]
    ## (comment:below will return p-values that are significant.)
    p.sig
}
```

Would this work?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at ?p.adjust

Answer (score 3):

You generally do not need to re-invent the wheel when doing any type of statistical analysis in R.

`p.adjust(p, method = 'hochberg', n = length(p))`

Comment: Although it should be noted that "hochberg" probably isn't the method they want here.  Taking a look at the documentation for p.adjust should get them what they want (assuming this isn't for homework and they are required to program it themselves).

Comment: If I use p.adjust, where should it be located in my code? Also, would my code above still work if I don't use p.adjust?

Comment: p.adjust does the entire procedure for you so you don't even need to write a function...

Answer (score 3):

*note major edit, see below*

I would agree that one need not re-implement the BH procedure, but disagree with previous answers that the "right way" to do this is with p-value adjustments. One might reasonably assume that "implement Benjamini-Hochberg" means find the critical value to maintain an expected false discovery rate, as described in Benjamini and Hochberg 1995; `stats::p.adjust` is actually modifying the p-values themselves to maintain an expected false discovery rate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/402217/171222

`sgof::BH` looks like a good implementation of the [Benjamini and Hochberg 1995 procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate)

*edit: it doesn't do what I thought! Putting the wrong part in italics, with corrections in* **bold**

Its worker function, `bh`, returns the *[critical value for test rejection]* **expected False Discovery Rate, given alpha and your p-values** (`FDR`), the adjusted p.values(for whatever they're worth) and the number of rejections in the set of p.values. Its arguments are the vector of p-values `u` and the *[desired False Discovery Rate]* **level of the tests you were thinking of using on the original p-values** `alpha`:

```
function(u, alpha = 0.05) {
  n = length(u)
  r = rank(u, ties.method = "max")
  bh = max(c(r[u <= (r/n) * alpha], 0), na.rm = T)
  su <- sort(u)
  jj <- which(u == 1)
  if (length(jj) != 0) 
    pi0 <- 1
  else pi0 <- min((-1/n) * sum(log(1 - u)), 1)
  if (bh == 0) {
    FDR_BH <- 0
  }
  else {
    FDR_BH <- round((pi0 * su[bh])/(ecdf(u)(su[bh])), 
                    4)
  }
  ad.p = numeric(n)
  ad.p[n] <- sort(u)[n]
  for (i in (n - 1):1) {
    ad.p[i] <- min(sort(u)[i] * (n/i), ad.p[i + 1])
  }
  return(c(list(Rejections = bh, FDR = min(FDR_BH, 1), 
                Adjusted.pvalues = sort(ad.p))))
}
```

We can take a vector of p-values and compute the critical p-value with `bh`. Interestingly, `bh` returns sorted adjusted p.values (and the wrapper `sgof::BH` also sorts the input p.values); I think `p.adjust` returns adjusted values in the order in which they were received.

```
set.seed(666)
my_p <- runif(10)
new_p <- p.adjust(my_p, method = "fdr")
new_p

BH_crit <- bh(my_p, alpha = 0.5)
BH_crit$FDR # critical p-value for 0.5 level false 
#discovery rate here would be ~ 0.13 

all.equal(new_p, BH_crit$Adjusted.pvalues) # FALSE
all.equal(sort(new_p), sort(BH_crit$Adjusted.pvalues))
```

*edit: why would the critical p-value be higher than alpha? Previous answer was clearly wrong*

**MAJOR EDIT**

I imagined **sgof** did what I wanted, but that was wrong... instead, it computes the expected FDR, given you have an individual test-level alpha in mind. I would want to go the other way... I set my expected false discovery rate, and get out my threshold p-value.

```
# set up some imagined p-values
set.seed(28)
nTest <- 50
p <- rbeta(nTest, 1.2, 5)
hist(p, breaks = 12)

# BH takes p and an FDR as inputs and returns hypothesis tests and the threshold p value
BH <- function(p, alpha = 0.05){
    u <- sort(p)
    uThresh <- alpha * (1:length(p))/length(p)
    k <- max(c(which((u<=uThresh)), 0), na.rm = TRUE)
    pCrit <- u[k]
    return(list(BHSig = c(rep(TRUE, k), rep(FALSE, length(p)-k))[order(order(p))]
                , pCrit = pCrit)
    )
}

# BHA does the p-value adjustments (this is a re-implementation from p.adjust that we all advocated against!)
BHA <- function(p){
    u <- sort(p, decreasing = TRUE)
    mult <- length(p)/(length(p):1)
    pNew <- cummin(u*mult)[order(order(-p))]
    return(pNew)
}

# test 
all.equal(BHA(p), p.adjust(p, method = "fdr"))

# Wrap both to get a fancy function like `sgof::BH`
BHAdjust <- function(p, FDR = 0.05, arr = c("p.orig", "none")){
    BHP <- BH(p, FDR)
    p.adj <- BHA(p)
    p.orig <- p
    message(paste0("For a ", FDR
                   , "-level false discovery rate, Threshold p-value = ", BHP$pCrit))
    out <- data.frame( p.orig
                      , significant_after_FDR = BHP$BHSig
                      , p.adj)
    if(arr == "none"){
        return(out)
    } 
    else {return(out[order(get(arr)),])}
}

# Run it
BHAdjust(p, FDR = 0.2, arr = "p.orig")
```

Comment: Michael this is great information about the nuances of `p.adjust`, though more a comment and currently not an actual answer to the question. Could you edit your answer to provide enough code to implement what you are referencing (ie, `sgof::BH`)? Link-only answers are likely to attract negative attention and get deleted - [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/668119) for more discussion about link-only answers - just trying to save you some headache!

Comment: you could cut and paste the `bh()` function from the guts of `sgof::BH` ...

Comment: Another thread discussing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56480971/8400969

Comment: This is great. But why `sort(u)` everytime in the loop? why not sort it just once,outside the loop since u does not change?

Comment: I looked very quickly and didn't find sgof on github. Seems like a good question for the package developers :P

Comment: More Stack Exchange discussions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/326322/171222