# Benjamini–Hochberg p.adjust in R - where is q*?

Tags: r

In R function p.adjust, I can't find which variable is q* from the original [Benjamini-Hochberg paper](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~doerge/BIOINFORM.D/FALL06/Benjamini%20and%20Y%20FDR.pdf).

R code:

```
...
}, BH = {
    i <- lp:1L
    o <- order(p, decreasing = TRUE)
    ro <- order(o)
    pmin(1, cummin(n/i * p[o]))[ro]
```

I'm confused because q*, as I understand it, should be chosen by the experimenter, and is often set at 0.05, but is not the same as alpha.

Comment: @Dason Hi I'm asking instead for what q* value is used in the R code for the p.adjust function.

Comment: You choose q*.  It's the level you want to control the false discovery rate at.  So if you want q* to be 0.05 then after you use p.adjust with BH then only "reject" the nulls that have values <= 0.05.

Comment: Just like how when just using p-values you choose the alpha level.  So just like how you are responsible for doing the comparison of your p-value to the alpha cutoff you need to compare the q-value (the output from the BH procedure) to your q* cutoff which dictates what false discovery rate you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure calculates the 'BH-adjusted p-values' which don't really exist, but they are still useful: all adjusted p-values below a particular fixed cutoff select the exact same hypotheses that would be selected by using the original Q-value procedure.  I found this quote (and actually whole section) from http://www.biostathandbook.com/multiplecomparisons.html
quite helpful:

> In my opinion "adjusted P values" are a little confusing, since
>   they're not really estimates of the probability (P) of anything. I
>   think it's better to give the raw P values and say which are
>   significant using the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure with your false
>   discovery rate, but if Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted P values are common
>   in the literature of your field, you might have to use them.