# Adjust significance threshold (alpha) according to FDR (Benjamini & Hochberg)` method in R

Tags: r

I'm aware about `p.adjust` function in `R` and it works well for my needs. However, now i'd like to correct `significance threshold (alpha)` instead of `p-values` themselves according to `FDR (Benjamini & Hochberg)` method.
For instance we have a ten of raw p-values:

```
0.0001,0.001,0.024,0.56,0.0077,0.55,0.0025,0.01,0.015,1
```

In case of Bonferroni it's very easy:

```
alpha_Bonferroni_corrected = 0.01/ number of tests (10 in our example)=0.001
```

But for `FDR` it will be a more tricky. Is there function in `R` for that?

Comment: `sgof::BH` might be a good option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699464/8400969

Answer (score 1):

mutoss package seems to offer greater flexibility

```
 library(mutoss)
 alpha <- 0.01
 set.seed(1234)
 p <-c(runif(10, min=0, max=0.01), runif(10, min=0.9, max=1))
 result <- adaptiveBH(p, alpha)
 result
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately i was not able to install `mutoss`. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mutoss’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘multtest’. I tried: `install.packages('multtest')` and got: package ‘multtest’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)

Comment: Try this if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) install.packages("BiocManager") BiocManager::install("multtest", version = "3.8"). http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/multtest.html

Comment: Now i got it, thanks! But there is no ``FDR` corrected `alpha` in the result although. While it's probably to some extent easy to find the corrected `alpha` from the `adaptiveBH` `R` function output in comparison to `p.adjust` indeed. In the mentioned above your example adjusted `alpha`=(1/20)*0.01, but in case of multiple significant p-values it would not be clear.